# How to open a new tab Chrome and Firefox using Selenium3 WebDriver with Java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver, chrome-web-driver, iedriverserver

I have a problem with Selenium 3 to open a new tab in Firefox and Chrome.

```
SeleniumTestBase.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");
```

Doesn’t work in Chrome and Firefox.

I could use the following code for Chrome but not for Firefox, in Firefox it open new Windows.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) SeleniumTestBase.getDriver();
js.executeScript("window.open('http://localhost:8080/games.html#machine','_blank');");
```

I used currently:

> - selenium-server-standalone: 3.8.1
> - chromedriver: 2.34
> - geckodriver: 0.19.1

Many thanks in advance.

Bes Regards,

Salai

Comment: You're sending a control-tab when you should be sending a control-t (tee)

Answer (score 4):

My solution, if anyone will need it in the future

```
driver.get('https://google.com')
last_handle = driver.current_window_handle
driver.execute_script('window.open("https://google.com", "new window")')
driver.switch_to.window(last_handle)
driver.close()
for i in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to.window(i)
driver.get('https://google.com.ua/')
```

Answer (score 1):

- To open a **`New Blank TAB`** in `Firefox` / `Chrome` / `Internet Explorer` you can use the following code block :

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('','_blank');");
  ```
- To open the `URL` **`http://localhost:8080/games.html#machine`** in a **`New TAB`** through `Firefox` / `Chrome` / `Internet Explorer` you can use the following code block :

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://localhost:8080/games.html#machine');");
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript to insert a link DOM node in current page, then click on it, remove it at last. DOM node should be supported by vary main browser.

```
public newTab(String url) {
    String script = 
        "var d=document,a=d.createElement('a');" + 
        "a.target='_blank';a.href='%s';a.innerHTML='new tab';" + 
        "d.body.appendChild(a);" + 
        "a.click();a.parentNode.removeChild(a);";

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(String.format(script, url));
}
```

Please execute below javascript in your browser's DevTool Console Tab, if it worked as expect, above Java Code should also be worked.

```
var d=document,a=d.createElement('a');a.target='_blank';a.href='https://angularjs.org/';a.innerHTML='new tab';d.body.appendChild(a);a.click();
```

Comment: this newTab() method open in firefox a new Windows. Not a tab.

Comment: I tried on my Firefox 57.0.4, it work fine.  I updated my answer, please execute the javascript in my answer on your firefox firstly.